# force download file with a download box using ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")

Tags: vbscript, activex, wsh, activexobject

could anyone please give me an example on how to force to show the save box using ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"), without php or other stuff !?

i would like to allow to download some mp3 file, instead those are being opened directly in the windows media player..
i just want to give the user the chance to choose whether download them or just open them

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Content-Disposition HTTP header in your web page.  It's the cross-browser supported method for forcing a SaveAs dialog to appear.

http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html